# How do I match two different big data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to learn that how can I match two different data frame in R? Like these dataframes;

```r
df1 = data.frame(Country = c("United state","Korea,Republic of","Macau","China, People's Republic of","united kingdom"))

df2 = data.frame(Country = c("United state of America","Korea","Macau SAR","China","England"))
```

I want to match these dataframes. And absolutely I can do it with using case_when command but I imagine if this was a big data and I wouldn't be able to see these differences.Then what will I have to do. Is there an easy way to do this? I would appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your ‘case_when()’ solution